# Rails 6, ActionCable display data contains HTML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I'm trying to use a partial via ActionCable as follows:

```
#app/channels/comments_channel.rb

class CommentsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel

  def self.broadcast(comment)
    broadcast_to comment.post, comment:
      CommentsController.render(partial: 'comments/comment', locals: { comment: comment})
  end


  def subscribed
    stream_for Post.last
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

here is the JS part:

```
#app/javascript/comments_channel.js

import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("CommentsChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    const commentsId = document.getElementById('comments');
    commentsId.append(data.comment);
  }
});
```

callin it in the `CommentsController`:

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
...
def create
  comment = @post.comments.create! comments_params
  CommentsMailer.submitted(comment).deliver_later
  CommentsChannel.broadcast(comment)
  redirect_to @post
end
```

and finally, the `comments/_comment` partial:

```
#app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
<p><%= comment.body%>--<%= comment.created_at.to_s(:long)%></p>
```

It works but displays HTML tags when posting a new comment. If I reload the page, no HTML tags displayed:

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to use [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) as follows in the `comments_channel.js`:

```js
#app/javascripts/channels/comments_channel.js
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("CommentsChannel", {

...
received(data) {
  const commentsId = document.getElementById('comments');
  commentsId.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', data.comment);
}
```

Hope this helps.